# Splash fragment wont display when using button.performClick()

Tags: android, android-fragments

edit: 2020.4.12 correct typo from Button.performClick() to button.performClick()

I am writing an app which should display a splash page/fragment for a
few seconds at start then display the next fragment in the navgraph. There are seven fragments in the navgraph which I can navigate around those fragments just fine.

The issue is with the splash fragment, I can only get the splash fragment to display/inflate when the `button.onClickListener` is set to accept a manual user
input -> click. (vs using `button.performClick()`)

The desired end result is to display a fragment layout consisting of an image view and a text view for a few seconds at app start before displaying the next fragment layout in the navgraph, without having the user to click or press anything.
I have tried using threadsleep, a runnable with a handler, and even a while loop with performClick(). None of which have yielded acceptable results.   The closest I have come to getting the desired result is the following:

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                     rootContainer: ViewGroup?,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflater(R.layout.fragment_splash, rootContainer, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            updateABode()
        }

       // pizzaLoop initialized to give about 4 seconds delay
       val pizzaLoop = 1500000000
       while (pizzaLoop > 0) {
           pizzaLoop--
           if (pizzaLoop == 0) {
              button.performClick()
           }
       }

    private fun updateABode {
        val ABode = "A"  // hard coded for testing purposes
        when (ABode) {
            "B" -> // for testing purposes only -- does nothing
            "A" -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_firmwareFragment)
        }
     }
}
```

With the pizzaLoop installed, the splash fragment will not inflate, but I do see the delay via the firmware screen update.  (intially all I get is a white blank screen then subsequent calls to the SplashFragment class show nothing but the firmwareFragment screen (next in the navgraph) -- and the pizzaLoop delay is noticable).

When I comment out the pizzaLoop then the splash fragment displays as intended but I have to click the button to bring up the next fragment in the navgraph (the rest of the navgraph works fine).

It's like the button.performClick() method is preventing the inflation of the splash fragment.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `button.performClick()`? Why don't you just call `updateABode()` directly?

Comment: well,   it has to do with the way setOnClickListener behaves.  The Listener will wait for the user --> forever!    if the user does not hit the button on the splash screen then it will just sit there until the pizzaLoop times out.....  using performClick to satisfy the Listener and move on to the next fragment..... at least that is/was the idea.

Comment: But you don't need to click the `Button` – programmatically or otherwise – to invoke `updateABode()`. You can just call it directly. Also, I just realized that you're using a `while` loop on the main thread to effect a delay, which is the issue. That is definitely not what you want to do. It hangs the UI thread. Instead, you could use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed()` method. For example, add `private val handler: Handler = Handler()`, `private val updateRunnable: Runnable = Runnable { updateABode() }` at the top, and use `handler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 4000)` in place of that `while`.

Comment: You will then want to add `handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)` inside the `button.setOnClickListener {}` block.

Comment: tried moving ABode() call into the pizzaLoop and removed the button.performClick(); but, here again the splash fragment does not get inflated (or at least it appears that way).   The splash fragment gets bypassed and the next fragment in the navgraph gets displayed.

Comment: Get rid of the loop altogether. That is what is preventing your `SplashFragment` from showing.

Comment: yes that's right.   but when I remove the loop now the Listener must wait for the user to hit the button on the splash fragment.

Comment: doesn't the button.setOnClickListener() need an input click/event to run the removeCallbacks() method?

Comment: you're awesome!!    Thank you -->  that did work.

Comment: Ah, good. To answer your question, yes, you do need a click for that `removeCallbacks()` to run, but what that line is saying, basically, is "if the user clicked the button, don't try to navigate to the next `Fragment` automatically, because it's already done". Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Instead of editing the solution into the question, please roll that back, and add it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 2020.4.12 TO PROPERLY POST SOLUTION.

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

private val handler: Handler = Handler()
private val updateRunnable: Runnable = Runnable { updateABode() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                     rootContainer: ViewGroup?,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return inflater.inflater(R.layout.fragment_splash, rootContainer, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 4000)
      }

    private fun updateABode {
        val ABode = "A"  // hard coded for testing purposes
        when (ABode) {
            "B" -> // for testing purposes only -- does nothing
            "A" -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_firmwareFragment)
        }
     }
}
```